# String format parsing in R

Tags: r, date

When I parse a character string into a date, Why does this not throw an error or an NA? I have tried the following

```
t <- "31-Oct-2012"
as.Date(t, format = "%d-%B-%Y") # this produces the expected result
as.Date(t, format = "%d-%B-%y") # I was expecting an NA
```

Instead I get

```
[1] "2020-10-31"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `%y` is for two digit year, so it takes only first two digits and ignores the rest. It treats `t` as

```
as.Date("31-Oct-20", format = "%d-%B-%y")
#[1] "2020-10-31"
```

This also works when you have anything after 2-digit year. See

```
as.Date("31-Oct-20ABC", format = "%d-%B-%y")
#[1] "2020-10-31"
```

R tries to "auto-complete" when there is less information, it returns some (incorrect) date for

```
as.Date("31-Oct-20", format = "%d-%B-%Y")
#[1] "0020-10-31"
```

but returns `NA` for

```
as.Date("31-Oct-ABC20", format = "%d-%B-%y")
#[1] NA
```

Comment: Okay, got it. But what’s the best way to force an error in that scenario.

Comment: @ashleych maybe you can check for condition before passing it to `as.Date`. So when you use `%y` make sure that there are only two digits in last two places.